# A neutral expression to understand that more cannot be done at a late stage?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

I sent an informal inquiry about an open position in a certain field of research. The application deadline was rather soon (less than one week), so the response was essentially "please apply if you are interested but we cannot give other advice at this late stage".

How would I respond to this? Something like

> Indeed, the application period closes soon. Thank you for the quick reply!

or just

> Thank you for the quick reply!

Answer (score 1):

Adding a cultural note, I don't think a native english speaker would reiterate the information they were given merely to show they understand (although a lot of phone support personnel are trained to do that, which is a little bit annoying).

I would probably just say, "Thank you - my application is attached."

Answer (score 0):

It isn't necessary to **acknowledge the deadline**, unless you just want to emphasize that.  In the context of a job application, it would be counter-productive, if not risky, to emphasize the deadline.

> Although the deadline was yesterday, I have attached my application.

The same can be said for homework, tasks of a job, appointments, and so on.

However, if you are responding to someone and reference the deadline, you would be extending a courtesy.

> Although the deadline was yesterday, I will look over your application.
>
> Even though the assignment was due four weeks ago, I will accept it now.